# Copy face data from one person group to another person group

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to copy data from one `persongroup` to another `persongroup` in `Azure Face API` in the same subscription . I tried the `snapshot`, while `apply` I am getting following error.

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro your issue on my side . Generally , this issue is caused by `applyScope` param while you [taking a snapshot](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/snapshot-take).

`applyScope` defines which Azure face service subscription that the snapshot could be applied to. If you just want to apply your snapshot within the same Azure face service subscription, you should take snapshot with request body below :

```
{
    "type": "PersonGroup",
    "objectId": "<PersonGroup ID>",
    "applyScope": ["<your Azure face service subscription ID>"],
    "userData": "{user provided user data}"
}
```

You can find the subscription ID on Azure portal :

[image]